# How can I purchase Mountain Lion on a computer and install it on a different computer?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, apple-id

I bought a used MacBook Pro 15″ with Lion and Windows dual boot. I accidentally dropped my Mac when it was on - everything was fine until I rebooted it and it got stuck on the grey screen, and I lost the dual boot so even Windows wouldn't start.

I've searched on the web, and it tells me to restore it via the internet with <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

I did it, but it asked me to update to Mountain Lion, so when I hit ok it says that my Apple ID has not been used to purchase Mountain Lion.

What can I do to purchase a new copy of Mountain Lion with my Apple ID? Can I use my other PC to purchase it with my ID, and after that download it when am in recovery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dropped your computer and it stopped booting right after that, you may now have a defective hard drive. I do not recommend attempting to re-install the operating system (Mountain Lion), as this may cause data loss.

My current recommendation is to confirm that you have a good backup of the data that is on your computer. If you do not have a backup, it may be necessary to attempt data recovery from the drive that is in the machine.

If you do have a current/valid backup of your data, I would recommend attempting to boot from another disk (CD/DVD, USB flash drive, etc.), and attempting to open Disk Utility to see if the software is reporting SMART failures with the drive. Alternately, very poor performance or clicking sounds while attempting to view/access the drive may be indicative of a defective drive.

Regardless, at this point, a system re-install is not likely to help with your issues (based on the problem description). If you are at all concerned about data loss, or are hesitant to attempt diagnosis/troubleshooting of your machine, I would recommend taking the machine into an [Apple Authorized Service Provider or Apple Store](https://locate.apple.com/country) for further assistance.

Comment: i have all my data in an external 1T HDD , and also there is no  Apple Authorized Service Provider. in my country

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can, purchase Mountain Lion with your Apple ID on one computer then install it on another.

### Edit:

---

The above is only true if your second computer is a mac. If your second computer is a PC you have to purchase a Snow Leopard DVD from apple.  Install it via the DVD, then upgrade to Mountain lion.

---

I would [replace your harddrive](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-13-15-17-mid-2009-how-to-upgrade-hard-drive-ssd.html) before reinstallation of Mac OS X.  If you have a small set of screwdrivers the procedure is easy.

The replacement drive I would buy would be a 2.5" non external powered HDD with a USB 3 enclosure. Open the enclosure, move the new drive to into your MBP, and your old drive into the enclosure.  Once you have installed Mac OS X 10.8 proceed to transfer the files you need from  your old drive, if it still works. If it does not you may want to try to repair it using disk utility, and try to extract the files again.

Alternatively you could just buy a replacement drive [here](http://www.macmemory.com/collections/internal-laptop-hard-drives) install the drive and then the OS. I have used this company before and their rates are ok. Or do a search on google and find a cheaper hard drive - up to you.

### Backups:

The other thing I would do is purchase a second external hard drive and set that up as a timemachine backup.

Comment: thank you for your help , i have an external 1T HDD with  all my data in it, i always do a backup , but now i need a new OS (don't have a recovery for it), as i know a Mountain Lion .

Comment: If both my and @EddieKelley s answers helped you, you should just upvote them.  Then you should "tick" the one that answered your question.  Upvotes are all the thanks we need ;-)

Comment: Cool, so all you really need to do is use your ID to purchase Mountain Lion, then replace the drive in the dropped laptop (or not up to you).  The non optional step is buying Mac OS X.

Comment: i have windows in my second computer , can you provide me the link where can i purchase a new copy? thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry, that cannot be done then.  You have to have a second mac.  The only way to do it is to purchase a Snow Leopard DVD from apple, then upgrade to Mountain Lion.

Comment: can i use my friend's Macbook ? 
and what can i do to bring the new mountain lion that i will purchase from his Mac to my Mac?

Comment: This link should help you, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4854, I am not sure but I think after you use your ID to purchase Mountain Lion, you can stop the installer on your friends computer. Then follow the steps for internet restore on your laptop.